# Evaluation of $\int\frac{1}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(x+k)}dx$

Tags: calculus

Evaluation of $\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(x+k)}dx$

$\bf{My\; Trial::}$We can write

$\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{\prod_{k=0}^{n}(x+k)}dx = \int \frac{1}{(x+0)\cdot(x+1)\cdot (x+2)..........(x+n)}dx$

Now Using Partial fraction.......

$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \frac{1}{(x+0)\cdot (x+1)\cdot (x+2).........(x+n)} = \frac{A_{1}}{x}+\frac{A_{2}}{(x+1)}+\frac{A_{3}}{(x+2)}+....+\frac{A_{n}}{(x+n)}.$

Now How can I solve after that

Help Required

Comment: Do you know how to integrate $1/x$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

Multiply either sides by $\prod_{r=0}^n(x+r)$

Set $\displaystyle x+s=0\iff x=-s,0\le s\le n$ to find $$1=A_{s+1}\left(\prod_{r=0,r\ne s}^n{r+n}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Note that
\begin{align}
&\Gamma\pars{x}={\Gamma\pars{x + 1} \over x}
={\Gamma\pars{x + 2} \over x\pars{x + 1}}
=\cdots={\Gamma\pars{x + n + 1} \over x\pars{x + 1}\ldots\pars{x + n}}
\\[3mm]\mbox{such that}&\quad
{1 \over x\pars{x + 1}\ldots\pars{x + n}}
={\Gamma\pars{x} \over \Gamma\pars{x + n + 1}}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int{\dd x \over x\pars{x + 1}\ldots\pars{x + n}}}
> =\int{\Gamma\pars{x} \over \Gamma\pars{x + n + 1}}\,\dd x
> ={1 \over n!}\int{\Gamma\pars{x}\Gamma\pars{n + 1}\over
> \Gamma\pars{x + n + 1}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over n!}\int\int_{0}^{1}t^{x - 1}\pars{1 - t}^{n}\,\dd t\,\dd x
> ={1 \over n!}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{n}\int t^{x - 1}\,\dd x\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over n!}\ \overbrace{%
> \int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t}^{n}{t^{x- 1} \over \ln\pars{t}}\,\dd t}
> ^{\ds{\mbox{Set}\ t \equiv \expo{-\xi}\ \imp\ \xi = -\ln\pars{t}}}\ =\
> {1 \over n!}\int_{\infty}^{0}\pars{1 - \expo{-\xi}}^{n}{\expo{-\pars{x- 1}\xi}\over -\xi}\,\pars{-\expo{-\xi}}\,\dd\xi
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{1 - \expo{-\xi}}^{n}\expo{-x\xi}\,{\dd\xi \over \xi}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over n!}\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{\xi}\bracks{%
> n\pars{1 - \expo{-\xi}}^{n - 1}\expo{-x\xi}
> -x\pars{1 - \expo{-\xi}}^{n}\expo{-x\xi}}\,\dd\xi
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over n!}\bracks{%
> x\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{\xi}\pars{1 - \expo{-\xi}}^{n}\expo{-x\xi}\,\dd\xi
> -n\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{\xi}\pars{1 - \expo{-\xi}}^{n - 1}\expo{-x\xi}\,\dd\xi}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{\xi}\pars{1 - \expo{-\xi}}^{m}\expo{-x\xi}\,\dd\xi
=\sum_{k = 0}^{m}{m \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{\xi}\expo{-\pars{k + x}\xi}\,\dd\xi
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{k = 0}^{m}{m \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}
\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\xi^{\mu}\expo{-\pars{k + x}\xi}\,\dd\xi
=\sum_{k = 0}^{m}{m \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}
\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{%
\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1} \over \pars{k + x}^{\mu + 1}}
\\[3mm]&=\sum_{k = 0}^{m}{m \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k + 1}\,
{\gamma + \ln\pars{k + x} \over k + x}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{\int{\dd x \over x\pars{x + 1}\ldots\pars{x + n}}}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over n!}\bracks{x\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k + 1}\,
> {\gamma + \ln\pars{k + x} \over k + x}
> -n\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1}{n - 1 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k + 1}\,
> {\gamma + \ln\pars{k + x} \over k + x}}
> \end{align}

$\ds{\large\tt\mbox{It will continue}\ldots}$

Answer (score 1):

Partial Fractions gives
$$
\begin{align}
\int\frac1{\prod_{k=0}^n(x+k)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!(n-k)!}\frac1{x+k}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\log(x+k)+C
\end{align}
$$